# How to compare two saved files with the filename of same url?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, url, compare

I'm saving many text files. Filenames are urls. File has whole html of webpage from url. All text files are saved in one folder.

My problem:
I need to compare two files of same url, but how?

- filenames of same webpage are the same, I cant save 2 files with the same name.
- add version of url is stupid because I cant add it into my webapplication.

Please help me how can I save two files of same webpage and compare their content.

Comment: maybe you can save the second version of the page into a temporary folder, then compare the contents

Comment: see if you can do somthing with Kdiff3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you checking this URL at two different times?  I would imagine so, because if you checked it twice in a row then there would be no changes.  So if you are checking at different times, why not place each one into a subfolder named after the date:

```
/etc/2011-01-02 2255/web-page-url.text
/etc/2011-02-02 2255/web-page-url.text
```

Then you don't have top worry about the two files having the same name.

Comment: JK, is it ok i will have tousends of folders on my server? look scary.. yes there are two differente times. each 24hour..